# Обязательно ли на хостинге указывать время выполнения cron на каждую минуту для laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Если у меня в Laravel schedule указано выполнение задачи daily(), то обязательно ли на хостинге, в настройках cron-a нужно вызывать schedule:run каждую минуту? Не могу точно понять как это работает.
И можно ли обойтись без laravel scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

> Если у меня в Laravel schedule указано выполнение задачи daily(), то обязательно ли на хостинге, в настройках cron-a нужно вызывать schedule:run каждую минуту?

Нет, можно раз в день. А в чём проблема вызывать каждую минуту? Более редкие schedule создают больше нагрузки за один раз. А так они более или менее размываются.

> И можно ли обойтись без laravel scheduler?

Можно. **Но ненужно**, это создаст лишние проблемы при переносе сайта на другой хостинг, и при делении сайта на облаках. И ещё добавит геморрою системному администратору если таковой будет.

Так кронки прописаны в PHP файле и запускаются по мере нагрузки. Тем-же cron. И если не работают то в ошибках будут тексты что кронка не запускалась столько-то времени. А если полагаться на простой cron то при переносе 100% потеряются необходимые задания, некто о них не вспомнит и спустя годик сайт пойдёт по *е.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Просто был сайт(не на laravel), на котором под каждую задачу мы создавали свой крон, каждый  из них запускался в разное время(каждую минуту, каждый  месяц и т.п). 
"Более редкие schedule создают больше нагрузки за один раз. А так они более или менее размываются." Почему, где про это почитать можно?